# jquery delegate clicks on a class but only if not clicking on a specific child

Tags: jquery, css, delegates

I have this delegate with jquery

```
$('body').delegate('.line-item','mouseup',function(){
        // more code gets run 
})
```

a sample of the dom with this class

```
<div class="line-item">
  <div class="thumb">
    Image goes here
  </div>
  <div class="title">
    Title goes here
  </div>
  <div class="destroy">
    Destroy Button goes here
  </div>
</div>
```

Want: when user clicks anywhere inside this div.line-item that's not the destroy class div, some code gets run to display this line item, but if they do click on that div.destroy, that line item won't get displayed but gets destroyed instead. So I don't know what the CSS selector should be like, I know that there's a :not selector, though I fail to cook up a selector with it that will do the trick,

any thoughts?

thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do

```
$('div.line-item').delegate('div:not(".destroy")', 'mouseup', function() {
    ....
})
```

### Check working example at http://jsfiddle.net/trVKF/2/

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I would use:

```
// to select the thumb and title
$("div.line-item div:not(.destroy)").click(function(){code...});

// to select destroy
$("div.line-item div.destroy").click(function(){});
```

Docs on "not" selector: http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add this to what you already have.

```
$('body').delegate('.destroy','mouseup',function(e){
    $(this).hide();  // or whatever 
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```